# Calling a function in another class in Android Java

Tags: java, android, methods, sharedpreferences, preferences

I have been looking around for an answer to this question and found a number of similar questions but none seemed to be quite similar enough and none of the solutions I found around the web solved the problem.

For an Android app I am writing, I need to save the Android preferences to a database. In order to do this I wanted to create a separate class with functions that I can call to sync, update etc the preferences. So this is the problem

- Call initiateSaveSettings() in the syncSettings class from the mainActivity

The way I try to do this now is by calling:

```
 syncSettings sync = new syncSettings();
 sync.initiateSettingSave();
```

Into the syncSettings class:

```
public class syncSettings extends Context {
      public void initiateSettingsSave(){
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(syncSettings.this, R.xml.root_preferences, false);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      }
}
```

etc.
The problem is that the SharedPreferences requires the extends Context and in order for that to work Android Studio gives the error to change syncSettings to

```
public abstract class syncSettings extends Context {
```

Doing this gives an error for new syncSettings() when calling the function, taking the abstract away gives the error in the syncSettings class. What can I do to make this work? If you need more information please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I am very much new to Android development so if I say or ask something dumb, that may very well be why...

Comment: Your preferences are an activity where user can chose things? like the habitual Settings activity apps usually have?

Comment: Yes, I use the default settings activity from Android Studio but I would like to create a way to sync those settings with a database when the app gets opened because the settings seem to save automatically locally.

Comment: Ok I understand, so what you want is to save the preferences to your remote database outside the device?

Comment: @josap97 I think you are calling ```sync.initiateSettingSave();``` method from an context(ie. activity or service). If i am correct then you should change the method as ```public void initiateSettingsSave(Context context)``` and remove that extends Context. Now you can pass activity or service object because both are child class of Context. Simply call ```sync.initiateSettingSave(this);``` from activity/service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class syncSettings {
         private Context context;

         public syncSettings(Context context){
             this.context = context;
         }
        
          public void initiateSettingsSave(){
                PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(syncSettings.this, R.xml.root_preferences, false);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
          }
    }
```

And in your activity:

```
syncSettings sync = new syncSettings(this);
 sync.initiateSettingSave();
```

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to work. I do need to iron out some other errors before testing properly but at least Android Studio is not angry anymore :).

Comment: Yes, this is not the definitive solution at your problem, this just get an instance of sharedPreferences correctly but now you have to take that values and save them in your remote db.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your reason for extends Context Ten. But you can use this class.

```
import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    
    public class PrefUtils {
    
        /**
         * Called to save supplied value in shared preferences against given key.
         * @param context Context of caller activity
         * @param key Key of value to save against
         * @param value Value to save
         */
        public static void saveToPrefs(Context context, String key, String value) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(key,value);
            editor.commit();
        }
    
        /**
         * Called to retrieve required value from shared preferences, identified by given key.
         * Default value will be returned of no value found or error occurred.
         * @param context Context of caller activity
         * @param key Key to find value against
         * @param defaultValue Value to return if no data found against given key
         * @return Return the value found against given key, default if not found or any error occurs
         */
        public static String getFromPrefs(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            try {
                return sharedPrefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 return defaultValue;
            }
        }
         /**
         * 
         * @param context Context of caller activity
         * @param key Key to delete from SharedPreferences
         */
        public static void removeFromPrefs(Context context, String key) {
             SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
             final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
             editor.remove(key);
             editor.commit();
        }
    }
```